# How to use same HelixViewport3D screen two different form c#

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I want to see the HelixViewport3D 3D area I designed in form 1 with a different camera angle in form 2.

I want to look at the production line that I can look at in the first form from the angle I want at the same time in the 2nd Form and the movements in Form 1 will appear in the 2nd Form at the same time.

I tried the following sample code but it didn't work

Visual Studio

```
public Window2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainWindow screen1 = new MainWindow();

    viewport3dScreen2 = screen1.viewPort3d;            // Window2 helixviewport3d name -> viewport3dScreen2

    viewport3dScreen2.Camera.LookDirection = new Vector3D(-144.937, 1.720, -14284.246);
    viewport3dScreen2.Camera.UpDirection = new Vector3D(-0.923, -0.009, -0.440);
    viewport3dScreen2.Camera.Position = new Point3D(1806.793, -519.229, 5594.084);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two viewpoints, and use same model for two viewports.